# Is it possible to type style sheets in Firebug fast and convenient ? (as in Aptana)

Tags: plugins, performance, firebug, typing, convenience-methods

For example, when I type the first of the parenthesis in Aptana, the second appears immediately, then I need only to press enter, it makes some white space, and I can type further.
A small feature that saves a lot of time!

But in Firebug it is not. So, is it possible to use that feature in Firebug? Is there any Firebug's plugin that allows to do that?

Thanks in advance)

Comment: firebug has a wealth of use. but its not an IDE :-( I'd be interested to see if there plugins are though

Comment: I wish I could do all my CSS in firebug. Much more real time and easy to see exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but if you create the classes in your css file and reload in your browser, then you can use firebug to just add attributes to them, and then you don't have to type any ':' or ';' either.

Comment: That is, in the HTML tab, on the right panels' Style tab. I find this the best way to be editing the CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use the **Web Developer** plugin for my CSS editing.  While Firebug is nice for quickly testing out one or two things, getting the styles out of firebug and back into your source file has always seemed like a pain to me.

With the Web Developer plugin (CSS -> Edit CSS), you can setup your whole stylesheet and see it take effect live. You can save your changes using the save button, or what I do is copy everything and paste it into my file.  I know this isn't a "fancy" IDE, with autocomplete or brace-balancing (it's just like Notepad), but I can accept that because of how nice it is to just type away unhindered and see the changes instantly. (And easier to save your work than it is with Firebug.)